# Toilet riser installation: The flange opening and the riser barely mate [updated]

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I am installing a toilet riser to allow installation of 2" floor insulation. The flange that is already in place has a large diameter pipe. The bottom of the riser is fairly small in diameter - the outermost dimension is almost exactly the same as the inner dimension of the flange. Will the wax ring safely deal with this? I am thinking that I want the wax ring pinched between the flange and the riser rather than blobbed like this. See below a cut view of the mating profile (wax not drawn). Is this going to be a leak issue? Something about it does not sit right with me. ID of flange is 4.8 inches, OD of riser base is 4.9".
[image: Toilet riser interface]
[image: Toilet flange, 4.8" ID]
[image: Toilet Riser base, 4.9" OD]

Comment: Is it possible to provide a few pictures so that we can see the actual problem you're dealing with?

Comment: Yeah, I'd need a more specific description and/or photos to help.

Comment: Updated with photos and dimensions

Comment: I'd suggest a replacement riser that's designed for your waste pipe size so that it's a better fit.

Comment: Toilet risers don't even advertise that dimension.